# Existence of orthogonal Hamel basis for infinite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, hamel-basis

Consider a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ that is infinite dimensional and equip it with an inner product (i.e. it is a Pre-Hilbert space). We know that $V$ has a basis set, say $S$, such that for any $v\in V$, $v=\sum_{v_s\in S}a_sv_s$ where only finitely many $a_s\in\mathbb{F}$ are non-zero. For a finite dimensional vector space we can orthogonalize the basis vectors using (Gram-Schmidt) but is it possible to do the same in an infinite dimensional vector space? 
I feel that if the basis were countable, we could do this but when the basis is uncountable (like the free vector space generated by an uncountable set $S$) it might not be. Is it possible to find an orthogonal uncountably infinite basis?

Comment: A Hamel (vector-space ) basis is a different concept than a Hilbert-space basis. In a separable infinite-dimensional  Hilbert space, the Gramm-Schmidt algorithm can be applied to a Hamel basis H to produce an orthonormal Hilbert-space basis B, but most of H will be "left out" because B must be countable but the cardinal of H is $2^{\aleph_0}$. And the algorithm will not necessarily end after a countable sequence, but after $\alpha$ steps, where $\alpha$ is some countable ordinal.

Comment: Why must $B$ be countable?

Comment: By a Hilbert space basis, do you mean a Schader basis?

Comment: I think to make Gram-Schmidt work You really need a separable Hilbert space ( i.e. You need a countable Schauder-basis)